# How to send Object in a multipart/form-data request without converting to string in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I have to pass the object in "multipart/form-data" request so that it can be received in downstream application (Java Spring) as List i.e custom class object. Metadata object contains only key and value

In Angular

```
interface Metadata{
 key:string;
 value:string;
}
```

In Angular I am using FormData to create the multipart request as given below.

```
metadatas = new Array<Metadata>();
// few values added in metadatas array.
 fileToUpload: File ; // contains file information

const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
formData.append('metadata',JSON.stringify(this.metadatas))
```

As **FormData append method definition says the "value: string | Blob"** so I need to convert my metadatas object to string using JSON.stringify(). 
But when I do so in Spring application (downstream), I can receive the object in String e.g

```
@PostMapping(path = "/file-upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> fileUpload(
        @RequestParam(name = "metadata", required = false) String metadata,
        @RequestParam(name = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println(metadata);
    System.out.println(file);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("example", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Above code is working and able to get the metadata and file data, **but as my API says it should be received in Java Object.** So my spring method definition it should be List. Again here the metdata is the object contain key and value.

In Java

```
public class Metadata {
private String key;
private String value;
 // getter and setters
}
```

In below code the metadata should be capture in List

```
@PostMapping(path = "/file-upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> fileUpload(
        @RequestParam(name = "metadata", required = false) List<Metadata> metadata,
        @RequestParam(name = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println(metadata);
    System.out.println(file);

    return new ResponseEntity<>("example", HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

I tried varies things with @RequestPart and @RequestParam, but nothing is working out. As per my understanding, I think that as I am converting the metadata in string while sending from angular hence I am able to received it in String object.

But in FormData I don't have any option to append the object directly as it allows string or Blob. ***Is there any other way to send the multipart object without converting to string in angular?***
Or ***even if we send the object using FormData how we can received the object in Java Class i.e. List in Spring Boot Application ?***

Please help me for getting the solution with the detail explanation as I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

What is working out for me is:

```
@PostMapping("/upload_pic")
    fun uploadPic(@RequestParam(IMAGE) image: MultipartFile?,
                  @RequestParam(GROUP_ID) groupId: String,
                  @RequestHeader(DEVICE_ID_HEADER_STRING) deviceId: String,
                  @RequestHeader(TOKEN_HEADER_STRING) authToken: String): ResponseEntity<StatusModel> {
```

All the annotation parameters are String constants.

BTW, this is in kotlin.

Comment: when the parameter are String its also working for me, but I want my parameter as Java custom object, as multipart supports sending of objects. But somewhere i find FormData in Angular 2 has limitation of sending the multipart request in string or Blob.